# Google Streetview Image API: calculate (automatically set) heading for given LatLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

Is it possible to calculate the heading that the Streetview Image API uses for a specific `LatLng`? I'd like to find out the heading while still using the the Streetview Image API. I'd like to determine where North, South, East and West are within the generated image.

I am aware that the Streetview Image API aims the camera in the "right direction" (thus, rotating the heading automatically towards the `LatLng` one specifies), which is the heading I am trying to figure out.

Comment: A LatLng is just a position, it does not have a heading, so I do not understand what you're trying to achieve? Especially given North always has a heading of zero, etc.

Comment: I'll clarify my question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So you're wanting the set [the heading to look towards a target lat/long, from your current lat/long](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/54460/9)?

Comment: I'm currently looking into `streetviewService` (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService), which is, I think, what I need. Thanks for your feedback! :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `getPhotographerPov` on the `StreetViewPanorama` class:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanorama

That has a `heading` property.

e.g.

```
var heading = yourPanorama.getPhotographerPov().heading;
```

Comment: For performance reasons I was residing to the Image API, rather than the Javascript API. It's got to do with one image rather than a fully interactive panorama (=possibly more load because of loading more images). Is it possible to use `getPhotographerPov().heading` without attaching a panorama to an element?

If possible, I'd like to make use of the Javascript API functionalities without the visual interactive panorama.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that you were using the Streetview Image API. It's a pity they don't seem to include `heading` data in the [Metadata](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) you can get.  You can use the StreetView as a service without having to display it; they sort of outline that [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService)

Comment: I think that this is what I'm looking for. I'll look into it! :)

Comment: This answer (well, Duncan's comment more specifically) pointed out which direction I should head. I added the following code, which works. Could you update your answer, with the code I put below? That way the right answer is available for reference.

`var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
sv.getPanorama({location: position, radius: 25}, processSVData);
function processSVData(data,status){
   if (status === 'OK') {
      // data.links[0].heading contains the heading!
   }
}`

Comment: ...as a side note: this still requires including the Google Maps Javascript API. But its usage is limited to fetching the API methods and the `StreetviewService`'s data, which is what I needed.